# Write a makefile to compile a .h .hpp and .cpp together into an executable

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

So I have a straightforward problem.

I have files `List.hpp`, `List.h`, and `test_list.cpp`

List.hpp contains function definitions for the List.h file.
The List.h file includes "List.hpp" in the 3rd to last line.
test_list.cpp runs the program and includes "List.h" at the top.

I need a makefile that will compile these into an executable "project.x".

So far  have this:

```
    proj2: List.o test_list.o
        gcc -o proj2.x List.o test_list.o

    List.o:
        gcc -c List.hpp


    test_list.o:
        gcc -c test_list.cpp

    clean:
        rm *.o proj2.x
```

However, it results in all kinds of errors, all dealing with lines that have `List <T>` in them, stating that `List` does not name a type. I think this is because I am not properly including the header file.

How would I make this makefile?

Comment: Why are you including `List.hpp` (function definitions) into the header? Also why is your function definition file not ending in `.cpp`?

Comment: I was given this List.h file and told not to touch it. The functions are in the .hpp and the .cpp file drives it all and produces output.

Comment: The person who told you this is incompetent, and will therefore probably be promoted to VP or given tenure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't compile .h or .hpp files.  You only compile .c or .cpp files.  You probably want something like(Indenting with tabs, not spaces, spaces is a SO and python thing, tabs are a makefile thing):

```
proj2: list.cpp list.hpp list.h
    g++ -o proj2.x list.cpp
clean:
    rm proj2.x
```

Also, in your C file, you will need:

```
#include "List.h" /* Note the quotes: *
#include <list.h>  * won't work       */
```

And likewise for your `#include "List.hpp"`.

Comment: Fixed.  proj2 now depends on: `list.cpp`, `list.hpp`, and `list.h` It doesn't compile `list.o`, since that is mostly useful if you have more than one cpp or c file.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the filename extensions and your description, you're compiling C++ code.

You should thus use a C++ compiler: `g++`.  `gcc` is a C compiler and doesn't know about C++.

You should really just let make compile your code for you, it knows what to do:

```
proj2: test_list.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm *.o proj2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite correctly. You haven't told it that test_list.o depends on `List.h`, so it won't know to re-compile when/if the header changes.

Comment: Your answer is cleaner.  Add in `#include "file.h"` for files in the current directory and the headers as dependencys.

Comment: Yes.  I was simply providing the (working) equivalent of the makefile in the question.  Adding a `test_list.o: List.hpp` will fix the prerequisite issue.

Comment: Actually, g++ and gcc are the same thing. gcc is the compiler itself, g++ is just gcc with flags activated with make gcc be able to compile c++ code.

Comment: Technically, both `g++` and `gcc` are just front-ends that manage the individual parts of the build process: preprocessing, assembly, compilation, and linking (all optional of course).  But if you're going to compile C++ code, you should use the `g++` front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You don't normally want to compile a header in isolation. It's intended to be included in a source file, and the source file is what you compile.

Given the implicit dependencies in a typical `make` utility, you can reduce your Makefile a little bit:

```
proj2.x: test_list.o
    g++ -o proj2.x test_list.o

test_list.o: test_list.cpp List.hpp

clean:
    -rm *.o proj2.x
```

At least assuming a reasonably recent version of `Make`, it'll already know how to compile a `.cpp` file to get a `.o` file.

If you're having compiler errors, chances are at least pretty fair that they stem from problems in the code, not in the Makefile. The obvious exceptions would be things like your C++ code failing to link properly, because you used `gcc` instead of `g++` to link it.

As an aside, the header dependency shown in:

```
test_list.o: test_list.cpp List.hpp
```

...is something that `gcc` can generate automatically with the `-MM` flag. For a tiny Makefile like this one, it's probably not worthwhile to mess with generating dependencies automatically, but for a large one it can be worthwhile. You can even include this as a step in the Makefile itself by running gcc with `-MM` to generate the dependencies (directing the output to a file) and including that file into a Makefile that does the real work).

More about dependency generation and how to use it in a Makefile:

http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html